# Saving keeps overwriting old saved infromation

Tags: c#

How do I stop this code from overwriting information that it has already saved? If I save the first load of information the next time I save it overwrites the first lot of data. Any help is very much appreciated

```
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("SaveFile.txt");
writeFile.WriteLine(txtFirstName.Text);
writeFile.WriteLine(txtSurname.Text);
writeFile.WriteLine(txtAge.Text);
writeFile.WriteLine(txtNumber.Text);
writeFile.WriteLine(txtEmail.Text);

writeFile.Close();
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on File I/O :)  
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336wast5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There's a parameter for the `StreamWriter` constructor that specifies whether you want to append to the end of the file or create a new file.

```
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("SaveFile.txt", true);
```

Comment: This is easily used in a `using` block as it should be. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`File.AppendAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
File.AppendAllLines("SaveFile.txt", new[] { txtFirstName.Text, 
                                            txtSurname.Text, 
                                            txtAge.Text, 
                                            txtNumber.Text, 
                                            txtEmail.Text });
```

It creates a `StreamWriter` internally with passing other parameter(s) as mentioned in the other answer, and using the `using` statement.Making your work easier.